# Which League of Legends items reduce opponents stats?

Tags: league-of-legends

I heard from my friends saying that there are items that reduce the opponents' defenses, e.g. [Abyssal Scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Abyssal_Scepter)

Where would we see list of all such items that reduces the enemy's stats?

Comment: Note that there is a League of Legends chat room on this site: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to interpret this as "items which reduce your opponents' **stats**". Correct me if there's a different answer you're looking for.

**Reducing your opponents' armor**

`Black Cleaver` reduces armor by a percentage on striking with physical damage.

**Reducing your opponents' magic resist**

`Abyssal Scepter` will passively reduce the magic resist of enemies near you.

`Wit's End` reduces the magic resist of targets hit by your basic attacks (and gives you the same amount).

**Reducing your opponents' attack speed**

`Frozen Heart` passively reduces attack speed of those around you.

`Warden's Mail` and `Randuin's Omen` reduce the attack speed of champions who hit you with basic attacks.

**Reducing your opponents' movement speed**

`Randuin's Omen` (active ability) reduces the movement speed of enemies near you.

`Frozen Mallet` reduces the movement speed of enemies you hit with basic attacks.

`Iceborn Gauntlet` reduces the movement speed of enemies in the area after you use an ability and hit something with a basic attack.

`Dead Man's Plate` reduces the movement speed of a character when you hit with a basic attack after charging it by moving around.

The active abilities of `Bilgewater Cutlass`, `Blade of the Ruined King`, and `Hextech Gunblade` will reduce the movement speed of your target. `Blade of the Ruined King` increases your speed by the amount that you reduce from your target.

`Rylai's Crystal Scepter` reduces the movement speed of anyone you hit with your damaging abilities.

`Stalker's Blade` (only available if you have the `Smite` summoner spell equipped) changes your `Smite` to `Chilling Smite`, which can be used on enemy champions to steal some of their movement speed.

`Face of the Mountain` grants an ally a shield which slows nearby enemies after 4 seconds.

`Frost Queen's Claim` creates ghosts which seek out enemy champions, revealing and slowing them.

`Righteous Glory` Gives a speed boost to nearby allies, then slows nearby enemies at the end of the speed boost.

**Reducing overall damage**

`Skirmisher's Sabre` (only available if you have the `Smite` summoner spell equipped) changes your `Smite` to `Challenging Smite`, which reduces the damage your target deals **to only you** and causes your basic attacks against the target to deal additional damage over time.

**Reducing healing**

`Morellonomicon` makes magic damage dealt to champions under 40% health apply Grievous Wounds, which reduces healing.

`Executioner's Calling` and `Mortal Reminder` apply Grievous Wounds upon dealing any physical damage.

Comment: There is also, adding on to reducing damage, the new Phantom Dancer passive, where the most recent person you auto attack will do 12% less damage to it.

Comment: `Skirmisher's Sabre` is not a jungler only item... it's just not, or almost never, bought by other roles. There's no item restricted to a role. Some people going top use `Smite`.

Comment: When a championn is considered a `jungler`?

Comment: @TrapHappy I added Skirmisher's Sabre and not Phantom Dancer because PD's effect is on you, not your opponent. Challenging Smite applies a debuff to your target, whereas PD applies a buff to yourself.

Comment: @NamGVU typically a character is called a jungler if they get their gold income or "farm" mostly from the jungle, as opposed to laners who get their gold income from lane minions.

Comment: You forgot Wit's End, Face of the Mountain, Frost Queen's Claim and anything applying Grievous Wounds.

Comment: And Twin Shadows

Comment: The active from Righteous Glory also slows, and you could add in Warden's Mail with Randuin's Omen and Frozen Heart.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see what you mean by strength so I'll go with each type of item reduction, maybe you'll find joy in one of these:

To reduce speed and atk speed:

- Frozen heart, randuin's omen, dead man's plate, rylai scepter, frozen gauntlet, hextech gunblade, frozen mallet... These one are the most common, I might have forgotten some.

To reduce enemy armor:

- Black cleaver, the two bows (forgot their name)

To reduce enemy magic resistance:

- abyssal scepter, sorcerer boots, void staff

The only things that reduce attack and ability power that I have in mind are Challenging smite and exhaust.

If you want to reduce the damage income just buy armor or magic resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Frozen Heart reduces the enemys attack speed by 20%.

Randuins Omen reduces the enemys attack speed by 15% when he hits you.

How exactly do you specify reducing enemys strength?

Does slowing count? Then there would be Frozen Mallet, Deadmans Plate, Rylies crystal scepter, Bilgerwater cutlass and what builds of it.

other debuffs? Armor reduction on hit with Black cleaver, grevious wounds from the new last whisper. And some more effects.

A list of all debuffs can be found [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Debuff)

Comment: FH was changed to 15% a long time ago.